# Trouble with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, linux, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm working on a Linux Centos virtual host with Hostgator. I'm using httpd version 2.2.15.

I configured mod_wsgi-4.4.13 with tags `--with-python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7` and `--enable-shared`. Python 2.6 is installed in `/usr/bin`. I have a symlink from `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.so.1.0` to `/usr/local/lib/libpython.2.7.so.1.0`.

My trouble is that when I run `python 'index.fcgi'` in `/var/www/html`, I get the error

> from mod_wsgi import get_wsgi_application
>   ImportError: /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so: undefined symbol: apr_bucket_shared_split

I've tried setting `$PYTHONHOME` to `/usr/local`. I've already set the `$LIBRARY_LD_PATH` variable (before doing that I couldn't get the library at all). I'm really not sure what to do next. Please help!

Thank you.

Comment: Have you set the WSGIPythonHome in your apache configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You have the following issues.

1 - The `--enable-shared` is not used with mod_wsgi build, but with the `configure` script of Python when building it. For more details see:

- https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Lack_Of_Python_Shared_Library

2 - From memory the shared library for Python should already gave been linked into `/usr/local/lib`. If it isn't something has gone wrong with your Python install. Even when installed in an alternate location such that the library isn't on the normal shared library search path, rather than symlinking the `libpython.2.7.so.1.0` into an appropriate directory, you are better off setting `LD_RUN_PATH` environment variable when building mod_wsgi from clean source code to be the directory where the Python shared library is. See:

- https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Unable_To_Find_Python_Shared_Library

3 - A `.fcgi` file has got nothing to do with mod_wsgi, so why are you running `python index.fcgi` in the first place?

4 - Nothing tells you to put in your code:

```
from mod_wsgi import get_wsgi_application
```

Where did you see that you needed to do that? Why that is even loading `mod_wsgi.so` I don't know as Python shouldn't be able to find it in the Apache modules directory like that as that directory isn't on the normal Python module search path.

In short, you appear to be doing things you haven't told us and what you are doing isn't what mod_wsgi documentation tells you to do. Please provide a pointer to the part of the official mod_wsgi documentation that you are using to set things up.

Comment: Thank you! You've given me some ideas to go on.

Comment: Hello again, I'm still hacking, trying to get this to work. I'm trying to set up django on hostgator, and their instructions said to use this index.fcgi file:

Comment: #!/home/username/mydjango/bin/python
import os
import sys

from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.insert(0, "/home/username/mydjango")
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "testproject.settings"

WSGIServer(get_wsgi_application()).run()     It worked on my shared reseller account, but not on my virtual private server account.

Comment: I should note that I haven't set up the DNS name servers on my virtual server, i'm only using http://[ipaddress]/index.fcgi/admin, which should (maybe?) lead to the django admin site as it does on my other account.  Thank you for your help.